# didSelectAnnotationView method creates an error

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

In my app, I have a mapView and few other components.
I have changed the view of annotation into my own icons, the icons gets displayed in the specific location of the the latitude and longitude.
But, when I click and hold the icons, it automatically gets converted into the anotations.
Please help me.
This is my map while loading

[image]

It becomes as such When I click and hold the annotations

[image]

```
didUpdateUserLocation
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D first;
first.latitude=13.040202;
first.longitude=80.24298;
myAnnotation.coordinate=first;
[locations addObject:myAnnotation];
[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];
}

viewForAnnotation:
{
static NSString *identifier = @"Wifintech";
pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView   dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if ( pinView == nil ) 
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car-side.png"]; 
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
}

didSelectAnnotationView
{
float latitude = [[view annotation ] coordinate].latitude;
float longitude = [[view annotation ] coordinate].longitude;
title_value=[[view annotation] title];
NSString * subtitle_val =[[view annotation] subtitle];
title_para.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",title_value,subtitle_val];
latitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
longitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude];

}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code, e.g. the mapView delegate methods and the code where you add the annotations to the map.

Comment: Why not copy-paste the code? Right now we are looking at an interpretation of your code. Debugging your real code is one thing, but debugging your interpretation of your code makes no sense. Unless this really is your code, then I can only say that you should learn Objective-C properly, as this is not correct syntax for methods.

Comment: I just had given some hint about my code, not full coding, with out knowing objective c, how coould I developed the above view.

Comment: I'm just trying to help you here, but if you give incomplete and in-accurate code, helping you becomes too much of an impossibility for me. Maybe some one else can help.

Comment: @chandru, This has been asked and answered many times on SO.  When using your own images, you need to create an MKAnnotationView not an MKPinAnnotationView.  Please try searching on SO for answers before posting questions (it will save everyone including you a lot of time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using your own images, you need to create an MKAnnotationView not an MKPinAnnotationView. Please try searching on SO for answers before posting questions (it will save everyone including you a lot of time) .

[MKAnnotationView ClassReference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView from

```
-mapView:viewForAnnotation:
```

Most likely the subclass overrides some method that are tracking the selected-state of the view and adjusting the image. I suspect this will not be the case when using MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a close look at the following documentation.
Also, maybe make sure that the view in didSelect.. method is actually a pinAnnotionView and that the image is what you think it is.

From the documentation on MKAnnotationView:

> Annotation views support the concept of a selection state, which determines whether the view is unselected, selected, or selected and displaying a standard callout view. The user toggles between the selection states through interactions with the annotation view. In the unselected state, the annotation view is displayed but not highlighted. In the selected state, the annotation is highlighted but the callout is not displayed. And finally, the annotation can be displayed both with a highlight and a callout. The callout view displays additional information such as a title string and controls for viewing more information. The title information is provided by the annotation object but your annotation view is responsible for providing any custom controls. For more information, see the subclassing notes.

Comment: Ya k, but I dont think ur answer is relevant to my query

Comment: Would you care to elaborate as to why it is not relevant to your query?

Comment: Actually I know about the things what you have given, my query is that why the icon image changes while clicking and dragging the button,

Comment: Actually, that piece of documentation addresses exactly that. Also, it hints you to the method that is curial to fixing your issue. However as you persist on not showing actual code, I can only guess at what it is that prevents your code from doing what you want it to do. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: I have given U full, couldnt u find the mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "LocationObject.h"
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;
@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *latitude_value;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *longitude_value;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title_value;
@property(nonatomic,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate;
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *locations;
@property(nonatomic,retain)  MKPointAnnotation * myAnnotation;
@property (readwrite) int tag;
@property(retain) MKPinAnnotationView *pinView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *title_para;
@property(assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordsArray;
@property(nonatomic,assign) MKPolyline * routeLine;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize latitude_value;
@synthesize longitude_value;
@synthesize title_value;
@synthesize myCoordinate;
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize locations;
@synthesize myAnnotation;
@synthesize tag;
@synthesize pinView;
@synthesize title_para;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize coordsArray;
@synthesize routeLine;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setMapView:nil];
[self setLatitude_value:nil];
[self setLongitude_value:nil];
[self setLatitude_value:nil];
[self setLongitude_value:nil];
[self setTitle_value:nil];
[self setTitle_para:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

MKPolylineView *polyLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:routeLine];
polyLineView.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
polyLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
polyLineView.lineWidth = 2;
return polyLineView;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

//map view : region nad annotation

```
#pragma mark map view delegate methods

-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
 //map region and center location  
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude=13.040223;
center.longitude=80.240995;

MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;

myRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
MKCoordinateRegion adjusted_region=[self.mapView regionThatFits:myRegion];

[self.mapView setRegion:adjusted_region animated:YES];
locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//first point

CLLocationCoordinate2D first;
first.latitude=13.040202;
first.longitude=80.24298;

myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
myAnnotation.coordinate=first;
myAnnotation.title=@"Wifin Technology";
myAnnotation.subtitle=@"Globus";
[locations addObject:myAnnotation];

//second point

CLLocationCoordinate2D second;
second.latitude=13.0406527;
second.longitude=80.2437427;

myAnnotation= [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
myAnnotation.coordinate=second;
myAnnotation.title=@"The Residency Towers";
myAnnotation.subtitle=@"Chennai";
[locations addObject:myAnnotation];

//third point

CLLocationCoordinate2D third;
third.latitude=13.040202;
third.longitude=80.240191;
myAnnotation= [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];

myAnnotation.coordinate=third;
myAnnotation.title=@"Rado Cool Zone";
myAnnotation.subtitle=@"Chennai";
[locations addObject:myAnnotation];


[self.mapView addAnnotations:locations];

title_para.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"The position displayed is Pondy Bazaar"];

coordsArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * locations.count);

int i = 0;
for (CLLocation *loc in locations) {
    coordsArray[i] = loc.coordinate;
    i++;
}

 routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordsArray 
                                                       count:locations.count];

[mapView addOverlay:routeLine];    


self.longitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",center.longitude];
 self.latitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",center.latitude];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
float latitude = [[view annotation ] coordinate].latitude;
float longitude = [[view annotation ] coordinate].longitude;
title_value=[[view annotation] title];
NSString * subtitle_val =[[view annotation] subtitle];
title_para.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",title_value,subtitle_val];
latitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitude];
longitude_value.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitude];
}
```

//Annotation view: icons

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{

pinView = nil; 

    static NSString *identifier = @"Wifintech";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if ( pinView == nil ) 
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                   initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];

        if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Wifin Technology"])
        {
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car-side.png"]; 
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        }
        else if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"The Residency Towers"]) 
        {
        pinView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"lorry-side.png"];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        }
        else if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Rado Cool Zone"])
        {
            //pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; 
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];    
            }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Nothing");
        }
return pinView;

}
@end
```

Comment: @joride, I have given my full coding

Comment: Yes I have seen it. I added another answer, it appears above your full code for some reason.